# Weird Sound Looping on Click

Tags: android, android-layout, audio

I simply have a sound that executes on a button click. Everything works fine in the emulator but sound #2 plays in an infinite loop when I run on my phone.

Could this be a phone issue I have downloaded other apps from the market that have had these weird sound loops. (I have a Droid 2)

Declarations:

```
final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
```

Button 1 code is as follows.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {                       
                    mp1.start();
                    textView1.setText("Hello");
                  }
            });
```

Button 2 code is as follows.(This is the loopy one)

```
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count++;      
            mp2.start();                
            iv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                    
            if (count == 5) {                 
                //I do some enabling of components in here      
            }                   
        }         
    });
```

I have tried

```
.stop()
.setLooping()
.pause()
```

as well as moving `.start()` after and before the if statement
All of these result in it still looping or no sound at all.

Comment: if you swap R.raw.sound1 with R.raw.sound2 does the looping problem stay with the 2nd media player or does it follow sound2?

Comment: @slayton when I switch sounds the sound that loops before still loops. Could you make your comment an answer and what would cause this. But what would cause this to play fine in some places but not everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you swap R.raw.sound1 with R.raw.sound2 does the looping problem stay with the 2nd media player or does it follow sound2?

I'm not an expert on the format of sound files, but it could be a problem with the file itself. Try opening the file in Audacity and cutting off the last 10 ms then save it as something new and see if the problem exists in the new file.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a whirl next time I get a chance

Answer (score 1):

Try to add OnCompletionListener for this MediaPlayers with

```
mp.stop();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html

Hope, it help you

Comment: Haven't had a lot of time but will look into this before, I've never used these, but might as well learn